# How to make a downward number triangle in Java?

Tags: java

So I have to write a program that displays this number pattern:

```
123456
 12345
  1234
   123
    12
     1
```

Here is the program I have:

```
public class PatternD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=6;i>=0;i--){
            for(int j=6;j>=1;j--){
                if(j>i){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(j);
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This displays:

```
654321
 54321
  4321
   321
    21
     1
```

I need to flip some numbers and I've tried a bunch of different things, but I'm still lost. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, your outer loop should stop when i = 0, not when i = -1. Second, the number you need to print is i - j + 1.

```
public class PatternD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=6;i>0;i--){
            for(int j=6;j>=1;j--){
                if(j>i){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(i - j + 1);
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops inside the first loop: one to add the spaces and one to print the numbers.